# Display a div on each page of the site

Tags: javascript

So I've made a chat application that I want to overlay on each page in my site, I can't simply put it in the head because I have too many pages

How could I do this?

Comment: You cant put in your head? What do you mean? A div cannot be placed in the head section.

Comment: How is the chat loaded? Consider injecting it using a script common to all pages.

Comment: i said i can't simply put the script on every page because it would take ages, i want to be able to simply make a script which would inject/show it on every page

Answer (score 1):

Create a div dynamically and append to your pages:

```
 function loadDiv()
 {
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.innerText = "This is my div";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
 }
```

Create a .js file and write the above code, include this .js file either in header or in the body of all required pages, call loadDiv() appropriately from pages.

Comment: well i said that i can't include it in every page that i want it in

Comment: Firstly, 'div' can't placed in header section, so you need a .js file which can be included in header/ body of the pages - internally appends a 'div'. There is no other mechanism or shortcut to achieve your requirement. The example shown above can be achieved using jquery but .js include is a must. You can create jquery-plugin but again need to include in all pages.

Comment: well, i'm pretty sure that there's a way

Comment: div can be included directly from server (if applicable in your scenario) - that can be achieved from a common place using base class approach.

Comment: @Sudipta_Maiti could you expand on that

Comment: Suppose you are using asp.net (just an assumption) and in asp.net all pages must be inherited from System.Web.UI.Page class. So create a base class like MyPageBase : System.Web.UI.Page and append div from MyPageBase or include in master page if available.

Comment: well i never said that i use asp.net

Comment: and it's definetly not an option

Answer (score 0):

You may put it in the footer section if the footer is common to all pages. And for an overlay you can always have a div floating anywhere with fixed position.

Comment: Well that's not much different to a header or a head

Comment: There must be some common part for all the pages right? The idea is to put the div in some common part so that is available to all the pages. If you don't have such structure its difficult to go about it. If you at least have  <head> common to all pages, you may inject your div through jquery in $(document).ready()

Comment: but i can't include the script itself

Comment: If you put some code it would be easier to answer

Comment: i need a script that would include a div in every page of my site

Comment: I understand that completely. But to achieve what you are saying there has be some thing that has to be put in every page or at least to some common part which is included in every page, be it a script or your div itself. There is no way to add script from nowhere. Or atleast there has to be a js file which will inject your div to your page.

Comment: well i do have a header which is common, so i bet that's what you're asking about @Amit

Comment: Right! So now what simply you can do is add your div to the header directly and show it dynamically with Javascript wherever you want on the page or may be with fixed position using css. That ways you will have your div in one single place.

Comment: but i can't add it to every single page because there's just too many pages to add it to